# How to avoid multiple value after joining three tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-query-store

So I have 3 tables, which is

Table 1 (header)

| id | basic_no |
| --- | --- |
| 1a | 1 |
| 2a | 2 |
| 3a | 3 |

Table 2 (selling)

| basic_no | curr | sell_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | YEN | 400 |
| 1 | USD | 3 |
| 2 | YEN | 10 |
| 3 | WON | 75 |

Table 3 (buying)

| basic_no | curr | buy_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | WON | 100 |
| 2 | USD | 15 |

My Expectation

| id | basic_no | sell_price | buy_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | 1 | 400 | null |
| 1a | 1 | 3 | null |
| 2a | 2 | 10 | null |
| 2a | 2 | null | 15 |
| 3a | 3 | 75 | null |
| 3a | 3 | null | 100 |

The problem is, I've been trying using LEFT JOIN on multiple tables but the output didn't met my expectations.

My Query:

```
SELECT h.basic_no, s.sell_price, b.buy_price
FROM header h LEFT JOIN selling s on a.basic_no = s.basic_no
LEFT JOIN buying b on h.basic_no = b.basic_no
```

My Output:

| id | basic_no | sell_price | buy_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | 1 | 400 | 100 |
| 1a | 1 | 400 | 15 |
| 1a | 1 | 3 | 100 |
| 1a | 1 | 3 | 15 |
| 2a | 2 | 10 | 100 |
| 2a | 2 | 10 | 15 |
| 3a | 3 | 75 | 15 |
| 3a | 3 | 75 | 100 |

It should has 4+2 = 6 rows, but my query gave me 4*2 = 8 rows. Kindly need your help. Thank you

Comment: Your query is invalid: you have `JOIN selling ON a.basic_no = s.basic_no` but you haven't declared `a` - only `h` and `s`.

Comment: What is the relevance of `sql-query-store` to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you want `selling` and `buying` records on separate rows. You need `UNION` for that.

```
SELECT basic_no, sell_price, NULL AS buy_price
FROM selling
UNION ALL
SELECT basic_no, NULL, buy_price
FROM buying
```

Joining this with `header` gives the following query.

```
SELECT h.id, h.basic_no, sb.sell_price, sb.buy_price
FROM header h
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT basic_no, sell_price, NULL AS buy_price
    FROM selling
    UNION ALL
    SELECT basic_no, NULL, buy_price
    FROM buying
) sb ON sb.basic_no = h.basic_no
```

Running this against the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE header (id char(2), basic_no int)
INSERT INTO header VALUES ('1a', 1), ('2a', 2), ('3a', 3)

CREATE TABLE selling (basic_no int, curr char(3), sell_price int)
INSERT INTO selling VALUES (1, 'YEN', 400), (1, 'USD', 3), (2, 'YEN', 10), (3, 'WON', 75)

CREATE TABLE buying (basic_no int, curr char(3), buy_price int)
INSERT INTO buying VALUES (3, 'WON', 100), (2, 'USD', 15)
```

Gives the following result set:

| id | basic_no | sell_price | buy_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | 1 | 400 | NULL |
| 1a | 1 | 3 | NULL |
| 2a | 2 | 10 | NULL |
| 2a | 2 | NULL | 15 |
| 3a | 3 | 75 | NULL |
| 3a | 3 | NULL | 100 |

Please feel free to add an appropriate `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

data

```
CREATE TABLE header(
   id       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
  ,basic_no INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO header
(id,basic_no) VALUES
('1a',1),
('2a',2),
('3a',3);

CREATE TABLE selling(
   basic_no   INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,curr       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  ,sell_price INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO selling
(basic_no,curr,sell_price) VALUES 
(1,'YEN',400),
(1,'USD',3),
(2,'YEN',10),
(3,'WON',75);


CREATE TABLE buying(
   basic_no  INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,curr      VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  ,buy_price INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO buying
(basic_no,curr,buy_price) VALUES
(3,'WON',100),
(2,'USD',15);
```

use `join` with `union` instead of `multiple join`

```
select 
  id, 
  header.basic_no, 
  sell_price, 
  null buy_price 
from 
  header 
  join selling on header.basic_no = selling.basic_no 
union 
select 
  id, 
  header.basic_no, 
  null sell_price, 
  buy_price 
from 
  header 
  join buying on header.basic_no = buying.basic_no 
order by 
  id, 
  header.basic_no, 
  sell_price desc
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vCbdbqlT)